# In what relation between tables to store cast votes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my application I have similar api for this at stackoverflow https://api.stackexchange.com/docs. 
I have addresses for casting votes for questions and answers. The problem is that I do not really know how to store such votes. There are two types of votes: `upvote` and `downvote`.

```
questions/{id}/upvote
questions/{id}/upvote/undo
questions/{id}/downvote
questions/{id}/downvote/undo
```

I have two entities: `UserEnttiy` and `QuestionEntity`.

I do not know which relations and mapping to cover these two entities. It seems to me that the votes should be on the list of the user, and in the subject of the question only the counter of these votes.

How to create the right mapping?

Comment: Are you asking what design to use or what the commands for actually storing the data should be? If it's design and you need to know what user voted what way, often it would be a third UserVoteEntity that stored the user reference, a question reference, and the way the user voted. Storing vote counts separately is a good idea, but this is all situational and there's other ways to do it too.

Comment: I want to know what is the best way to store the votes cast.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpliest way is throw away "/undo" and create in QuestionEntity another attribute which contains number of votes. If someone click upvote number getting higher also if click downvote - number is going down.